# How can I factor matrices into specific shapes?

Tags: python, math, matrix, factors

I have a matrix with a shape of (30000, 10). I want to factor this into matrices with the shapes (30000, 512) and (512, 10). Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so in code (ideally python)?

For example, if there was a matrix such as this:

```py
c = np.array([[39, 21],
       [87 , 54],
       [135, 87],
       [183, 120]])
```

I would want to be able to get two matrices that multiply to get `c` while specifying the shapes. Say the I wanted to find two matrices with shapes `(4,3)` and `(3,2)`, I would get these arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[10,11,12]])

b = np.array([[2,3],
          [5,6],
          [9,2]])
```

Comment: Can you give us an example with a small matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is non-negative, you can use non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) to obtain such a solution. You can refer to [sklearn's NMF implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html)

Example:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

x = np.random.rand(30000,10)
model = NMF(n_components=512, init='random', random_state=0)
W = model.fit_transform(x) # W.shape = (30000,512)
H = model.components_ # W.shape = (512,10)
```

Comment: Should W = model.fit_transform(a) be W = model.fit_transform(x)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo. Corrected!